# Webpack can't resolve module in directory

Tags: webpack, requirejs

I am migrating an old RequireJS/CommonJS/AMD/Knockout thing to Webpack. When I try to compile the code, I get an error message:

> ERROR in ./Scripts/pbkdf2.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Scripts/sha1' in 'C:@Code\Scripts'

I understand the error, but can't get Webpack to resolve the `/Scripts` directory for the `/Scripts/sha1` dependency.

Relevant Webpack configuration options:

```
config = {
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `/Scripts/pbkdf2.js` file is defined like this:

```
define("/Scripts/pbkdf2", ["/Scripts/sha1"], function (sha1) {
  ...
})
```

I tried adding a `resolve.module` for `path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts")`, but that didn't work. I think it might work if I do than and then also remove the `/Scripts/` part from `/Scripts/sha1`, but I'd like to avoid going through the whole project and updating all of those references.

How do I get Webpack to resolve these subdirectories based on the root of my project? I thought the `path.resolve(__dirname)` did that, but it seems like it is not the project root, but instead it is the directory that the file is being executed on?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve my issue by providing a `resolve.alias` that maps `/Scripts/*` modules to the appropriate base directory. I guess RequireJS was trying to resolve the path relatively instead of using my Webpack `resolve.modules` configuration.

Relevant changes to config:

```
config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "/Scripts": path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts")
    }
  }
}
```

This alias matches all require modules that begin with `/Scripts`, so it seems to be able to resolve my modules as I expect now.